# How can I mount an encrypted disk from the command line?

Tags: terminal, hard-drive, disk-utility, mount, encryption

When I type `diskutil mount disk3` in the terminal, it says **Volume(s) mounted successfully**. However, the disk is not mounted and I can confirm this by opening the GUI of Disk Utility.app and also the disk does not show in the Finder.

I suspect this is because the disk is encrypted and the terminal command is not passing via "Keychain" to retrieve the password for the encrypted disk.

What do you think? Is there a way to mount encrypted disks via the command line?
Thanks.

Answer (score 31):

You want to run `diskutil coreStorage unlockVolume <UUID>`, where the UUID is the Logical Volume UUID associated with your encrypted disk, `/dev/disk3`.  You can get the lvUUID by running `diskutil cs list` in the terminal and looking for the output related to `/dev/disk3`.  The identifier is a long string that would look something like this 'B807C2A0-577F-3DB0-9002-F82B9137696C'.

It will prompt you for a password at that point and if it's correct, unlock the disk.

Comment: This worked great.  It should be said that when you do a diskutil coreStorage list, you may encounter a stack of such ID's representing the device.  In my case, the stack looks like:  Logical Volume Group, Physical Volume, Logical Volume Family, and finally Logical Volume.  You want to use the ID shown with Logical Volume, which is the last one, for your unlockVolume call.

Comment: Note for modern apfs file systems you should use `diskutil apfs unlockVolume` and `diskutil apfs list`

Answer (score 10):

You can use `hdiutil` to mount a disk image that is protected with a passphrase.

```
hdiutil attach -agentpass /path/to/image.dmg
```

That should attempt to mount the disk image, prompting you for the passphrase. If it's encrypted with a public key, you can pass that using option `-pubkey`.

Comment: Thanks. This isn't quite what I"m looking for. It doesn't ask for the password the disk is encrypted with. It asks for my local account password twice before attaching the disk.

Comment: Oddly enough it only prompts me for a password when I *omit* the -agentpass option.

Comment: Your answer, using hdiutil, has nothing to do with the OP and question asked, which was about mounting an encrypted disk from the command line, **not** an encrypted disk image, which are two different things! foundling's answer, using diskutil, is the correct answer!

Comment: Good answer. hdiutil is the answer for another related question I had: how to unmount encrypted dmg and "lock" it for it start to ask password on new mount. Answer is `hdiutil eject /Volumes/your_volume`

Answer (score 2):

I can't see what I'm doing differently today, but

```
diskutil unmount disk3
```

and

```
diskutil mount disk3
```

are working fine and properly unmounting and mounting the HDD and it is viewable in the Finder. Encryption doesn't seem to have anything to do with it.

Comment: Are you answering your own question here? If so, is your answer that the problem simply went away?

Answer (score 0):

Enter Recovery Mode. Open Terminal app. Launch Disk Utility app from the command line by executing:

`/Applications/Utilities/Disk\ Utility.app/Contents/MacOS/Disk\ Utility`

Select the lock drive and click mount. It will prompt for a password if encrypted

You can then enter your root volume normally.